# A Function object is a constructor from LLVM pass

Tags: llvm

I am writing a llvm pass. I have a Function object from llvm and I want to know if this one is a constructor of a class or not. How can I do it? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well... Looks like the only thing you could do is to try to demangle the function name and try to deduce whether it's constructor or not. Though, it's not 100% precise since one would need to handle multiple mangling schemes.

Answer (score 0):

As Anton said, we can demangle the function name.

LLVM has a demangler in `llvm/Demangle/Demangle.h`.
The usage can be seen in

[how to get function base name from managled function name using llvm ItaniumDemangle api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66803467/how-to-get-function-base-name-from-managled-function-name-using-llvm-itaniumdema)

```cpp
  ItaniumPartialDemangler Demangler; 
  Demangler.partialDemangle(F.getName().str().c_str());
  if (Demangler.isCtorOrDtor()){
    outs() << MF.getName() << " is constructor !\n";
  }
```

This may not be an elegant way to determine whether a function is a constructor or not as it may cause performance issues in compilation.
I am still waiting for a better approach.